# Can Diablo 3 be played in 3D?

Tags: diablo-iii

My graphics card is capable of playing games in 3D. I was just wondering if Diablo 3 supports 3D display and if so how would one go about setting this up?

Comment: Have you tried [these instructions on TriDef.com](http://www.tridef.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2316&start=10)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is [no true 3D support](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/D3supportedvideo) built into Diablo 3, as "3D stereo displays are not officially supported".  It very well [may be patched in](http://vlan.hubpages.com/hub/Blizzard-meets-3D-The-Third-Dimension-in-Diablo-3-Starcraft-2-and-WoW-Cataclysm) after the initial glitches are ironed out.

Some users are playing with stereoscopic 3D using Nvidia's glasses as [described here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4927183660) and one person references <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> as the toggle, but it seems that this is NVidia's technology and not built into Diablo 3 itself.

Comment: If you like his answer you can click the green check mark to mark this question with an accepted answer. It also earns you a Perfect Star Ruby in the Diablo 3 Contest.

Comment: @dennis ...and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

I use Tridef 3D on my Samsung Syncmaster SA950, Diablo 3 looks amazing.